# Is there any way to optimize this stored procedure?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, optimization, pivot-table

So I have this wicked long and complex stored procedure that I have constructed based on tutorials for "pivoting". I was wondering if anyone on here who is proficient in MySQL would mind discussing with me, how to make this cleaner, and/or perform better. Also, when the query returns no results between the dates specified, it produces a MySQL syntax error in the "call reading_pivot(...)" clause.

Here is the code:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER=`csonet_web_user`@`%` PROCEDURE `reading_pivot`(
    IN begin_date datetime,
    IN end_date datetime,
    IN node_string varchar(255),
    IN sensor_string varchar(255)
)
BEGIN
SET session group_concat_max_len = 4096;
SET @sql = null;
SELECT group_concat(distinct concat('MAX(IF(sensorId = ''', sensorId, ''', collectedValue * multiplier + offset, NULL)) AS ''', sensorId,'''')) INTO @sql FROM
    (
        SELECT inodes.id AS nodeId, from_unixtime(300 * round(unix_timestamp(inodes_data.time)/300)) AS dateCollected, TRIM(inodes.descr) AS parentId,
        1 AS sensorNumber, CONCAT('c', TRIM(cast(inodes.id as char(6) charset latin1)), '_1') AS sensorId, inodes.sensType1 AS sensorTitle, inodes.a1 AS multiplier, inodes.b1 AS offset, inodes_data.sens1 AS collectedValue, 
        inodes_structure_data.sensor1_units AS unitsOfMeasure
            FROM CSO_CITY_15.inodes
            INNER JOIN CSO_CITY_15.inodes_structure_data
                ON inodes.id = inodes_structure_data.id
            INNER JOIN CSO_CITY_15.inodes_data inodes_data
                ON inodes.id = inodes_data.i_id
            WHERE find_in_set(TRIM(cast(inodes.id as char(6) charset latin1)), node_string)
                AND inodes_data.time BETWEEN begin_date AND end_date

        UNION ALL

        SELECT inodes.id, from_unixtime(300 * round(unix_timestamp(inodes_data.time)/300)), TRIM(inodes.descr),
        2, CONCAT('c', TRIM(cast(inodes.id as char(6) charset latin1)), '_2'), inodes.sensType2, inodes.a2, inodes.b2, inodes_data.sens2, inodes_structure_data.sensor2_units
            FROM CSO_CITY_15.inodes
            INNER JOIN CSO_CITY_15.inodes_structure_data
                ON inodes.id = inodes_structure_data.id
            INNER JOIN CSO_CITY_15.inodes_data inodes_data
                ON inodes.id = inodes_data.i_id
            WHERE find_in_set(TRIM(cast(inodes.id as char(6) charset latin1)), node_string)
                AND inodes_data.time BETWEEN begin_date AND end_date

        UNION ALL

        SELECT inodes.id, from_unixtime(300 * round(unix_timestamp(inodes_data.time)/300)), TRIM(inodes.descr),
        3, CONCAT('c', TRIM(cast(inodes.id as char(6) charset latin1)), '_3'), inodes.sensType3, inodes.a3, inodes.b3, inodes_data.sens3, inodes_structure_data.sensor3_units
            FROM CSO_CITY_15.inodes
            INNER JOIN CSO_CITY_15.inodes_structure_data
                ON inodes.id = inodes_structure_data.id
            INNER JOIN CSO_CITY_15.inodes_data inodes_data
                ON inodes.id = inodes_data.i_id
            WHERE find_in_set(TRIM(cast(inodes.id as char(6) charset latin1)), node_string)
                AND inodes_data.time BETWEEN begin_date AND end_date

        UNION ALL

        SELECT inodes.id, from_unixtime(300 * round(unix_timestamp(inodes_data.time)/300)), TRIM(inodes.descr),
        4, CONCAT('c', TRIM(cast(inodes.id as char(6) charset latin1)), '_4'), inodes.sensType4, inodes.a4, inodes.b4, inodes_data.sens4, inodes_structure_data.sensor4_units
            FROM CSO_CITY_15.inodes
            INNER JOIN CSO_CITY_15.inodes_structure_data
                ON inodes.id = inodes_structure_data.id
            INNER JOIN CSO_CITY_15.inodes_data inodes_data
                ON inodes.id = inodes_data.i_id
            WHERE find_in_set(TRIM(cast(inodes.id as char(6) charset latin1)), node_string)
                AND inodes_data.time BETWEEN begin_date AND end_date

    ) sensor_reading
WHERE
    find_in_set(sensorId, sensor_string)
ORDER BY dateCollected;

SET @sql = concat('SELECT dateCollected, ', @sql, ' FROM (
        SELECT inodes.id AS nodeId, from_unixtime(300 * round(unix_timestamp(inodes_data.time)/300)) AS dateCollected, TRIM(inodes.descr) AS parentId,
        1 AS sensorNumber, CONCAT(''c'', TRIM(cast(inodes.id as char(6) charset latin1)), ''_1'') AS sensorId, inodes.sensType1 AS sensorTitle, inodes.a1 AS multiplier, inodes.b1 AS offset, inodes_data.sens1 AS collectedValue, 
        inodes_structure_data.sensor1_units AS unitsOfMeasure
            FROM CSO_CITY_15.inodes
            INNER JOIN CSO_CITY_15.inodes_structure_data
                ON inodes.id = inodes_structure_data.id
            INNER JOIN CSO_CITY_15.inodes_data inodes_data
                ON inodes.id = inodes_data.i_id
            WHERE find_in_set(TRIM(cast(inodes.id as char(6) charset latin1)), ''',node_string,''')
                AND inodes_data.time BETWEEN ''',begin_date,''' AND ''',end_date,'''

        UNION ALL

        SELECT inodes.id, from_unixtime(300 * round(unix_timestamp(inodes_data.time)/300)), TRIM(inodes.descr),
        2, CONCAT(''c'', TRIM(cast(inodes.id as char(6) charset latin1)), ''_2''), inodes.sensType2, inodes.a2, inodes.b2, inodes_data.sens2, inodes_structure_data.sensor2_units
            FROM CSO_CITY_15.inodes
            INNER JOIN CSO_CITY_15.inodes_structure_data
                ON inodes.id = inodes_structure_data.id
            INNER JOIN CSO_CITY_15.inodes_data inodes_data
                ON inodes.id = inodes_data.i_id
            WHERE find_in_set(TRIM(cast(inodes.id as char(6) charset latin1)), ''',node_string,''')
                AND inodes_data.time BETWEEN ''',begin_date,''' AND ''',end_date,'''

        UNION ALL

        SELECT inodes.id, from_unixtime(300 * round(unix_timestamp(inodes_data.time)/300)), TRIM(inodes.descr),
        3, CONCAT(''c'', TRIM(cast(inodes.id as char(6) charset latin1)), ''_3''), inodes.sensType3, inodes.a3, inodes.b3, inodes_data.sens3, inodes_structure_data.sensor3_units
            FROM CSO_CITY_15.inodes
            INNER JOIN CSO_CITY_15.inodes_structure_data
                ON inodes.id = inodes_structure_data.id
            INNER JOIN CSO_CITY_15.inodes_data inodes_data
                ON inodes.id = inodes_data.i_id
            WHERE find_in_set(TRIM(cast(inodes.id as char(6) charset latin1)), ''',node_string,''')
                AND inodes_data.time BETWEEN ''',begin_date,''' AND ''',end_date,'''

        UNION ALL

        SELECT inodes.id, from_unixtime(300 * round(unix_timestamp(inodes_data.time)/300)), TRIM(inodes.descr),
        4, CONCAT(''c'', TRIM(cast(inodes.id as char(6) charset latin1)), ''_4''), inodes.sensType4, inodes.a4, inodes.b4, inodes_data.sens4, inodes_structure_data.sensor4_units
            FROM CSO_CITY_15.inodes
            INNER JOIN CSO_CITY_15.inodes_structure_data
                ON inodes.id = inodes_structure_data.id
            INNER JOIN CSO_CITY_15.inodes_data inodes_data
                ON inodes.id = inodes_data.i_id
            WHERE find_in_set(TRIM(cast(inodes.id as char(6) charset latin1)), ''',node_string,''')
                AND inodes_data.time BETWEEN ''',begin_date,''' AND ''',end_date,'''

    ) sensor_reading WHERE
    find_in_set(sensorId, ''',sensor_string,''')
 group by dateCollected');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;

END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Sample results for 
`call CSO_CITY_3.reading_pivot('2015-07-07','2015-07-08','26121','c26121_1,c26121_2')`

```
+---------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
| dateCollected       | c26121_1           | c26121_2           |
+---------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
| 2015-07-07 00:00:00 | 0.8928999044001102 |   1.73075295612216 |
| 2015-07-07 00:05:00 | 0.8787019047886133 |   1.73075295612216 |
| 2015-07-07 00:10:00 | 0.8928999044001102 |  1.759125955402851 |
| 2015-07-07 00:15:00 | 0.8787019047886133 |   1.73075295612216 |
| 2015-07-07 00:20:00 | 0.8928999044001102 | 1.7023799568414688 |
| 2015-07-07 00:25:00 | 0.8928999044001102 |  1.759125955402851 |
| 2015-07-07 00:30:00 | 0.8928999044001102 |   1.73075295612216 |
| 2015-07-07 00:35:00 | 0.9070979040116072 |  1.759125955402851 |
| 2015-07-07 00:40:00 | 0.8787019047886133 |   1.73075295612216 |
| 2015-07-07 00:45:00 | 0.8928999044001102 |   1.73075295612216 |
| 2015-07-07 00:50:00 |  0.935493903234601 | 1.7023799568414688 |
| 2015-07-07 00:55:00 | 0.8928999044001102 |   1.73075295612216 |
| 2015-07-07 01:00:00 | 0.8928999044001102 |   1.73075295612216 |
| 2015-07-07 01:05:00 | 0.8928999044001102 |   1.73075295612216 |
```

Any and all help or guidance is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you dynamically construct the query, then execute it.  [*Here*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/pivot) is an example and how it works.